# Complex integral over an inverse sinh function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Suppose I want to calculate the parametric integral

$I_z = \int_{\beta-i\infty}^{\beta+i\infty}\frac{\exp(sz)}{\sinh^N(s)}ds$

for a natural number $N$ and a parameter $z \in \mathbb R$, the variable $\beta \in \mathbb R$ is chosen such that all singularities lie in the left half-plane or on imaginary axis. I would use residue theorem and the representation

$\sinh(s)=s \prod_{k=1}^\infty (1+\frac{is}{\pi k})(1-\frac{is}{\pi k})$.

Poles are at every $s=i\pi k$ for any $k \in \mathbb N$ and all poles are of order $N$. Notice that the denominator is invariant under shifts $s \mapsto s+i\pi$, so every pole would give us the same residual denominator value.

There is needed the $N$-th derivative, which will make the expression really complex. Am I on the right way or are there better strategies?

Moreover, I am thinking that it can be linked with zeta function, because it has a quite similar integral expression, maybe I just have to reorganize contour integration before I can use it...

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could make use of $\frac{1}{\sinh ^{(n)}(s)}=(-i)^{1-n} \csc \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}-i s\right)$ so your integral looks like $(2 \pi i)\,(-i)^{1-n}$ times the inverse Laplace transform of $\csc\left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}-i s\right)$.

Comment: As written, the integral doesn't converge.